# C++ Strange hex dump of WSAsend Packets

Tags: c++, hex, dump, packets

http://prntscr.com/2ctnoz

I'm hooking a WSAsend function and dumping the packets.  ASCII dump works but HEX dump sometimes shows things like you can see on the screen (the FFFFFFDD), any idea why?

code:

```
int WINAPI myWSASend(SOCKET s, LPWSABUF lpBuffers, DWORD dwBufferCount, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesSent, DWORD dwFlags, LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine)
{   
    //Packet Log
    if (bLogPacketS == TRUE)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lpBuffers->len; i = i + 8)
        {
            printf("%02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\t\t%c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n",
                  (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i], (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+1], (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+2],
                  (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+3], (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+4], (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+5],
                  (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+6], (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+7],
                  (drawable((unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i])) ? (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i] : '.',
                  (drawable((unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+1])) ? (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+1] : '.',
                  (drawable((unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+2])) ? (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+2] : '.',
                  (drawable((unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+3])) ? (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+3] : '.',
                  (drawable((unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+4])) ? (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+4] : '.',
                  (drawable((unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+5])) ? (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+5] : '.',
                  (drawable((unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+6])) ? (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+6] : '.',
                  (drawable((unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+7])) ? (unsigned int)lpBuffers->buf[i+7] : '.');
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    return (oWSASend)(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesSent, dwFlags, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine);
}

bool drawable(unsigned int value)
{
    if (value > 32 && value < 127)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Is there some kind of 'printf Of The Year' competition going on?

Comment: if so, i would probably win, i know its not the best way to do it but i couldnt think of a better way

Comment: @MartinJames: It's not *that* bad...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I had no answer for the OP, so I resorted to a bit of Christmas fun. The question is kinda interesting though, so I've upvoted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're casting to the wrong type.**

You only want to change signedness, but you're expanding each byte to a four-byte word as well. In the presence of signed-to-unsigned conversion (and the resulting negative-value wraparound), this is resulting in a monstrously high value.

---

Each "element" of `lpBuffers->buf[i]` is a `char`, but you're casting to `unsigned int`. If your `char` is signed on your system then `0xDD` is off the top of the type's range, so it wraps around to `-35`. Then casting it to `unsigned int` results in `0xFFFFFFDD`.

The `printf` specifier `%02X` won't truncate this.

Presumably you wish to interpret all the bytes as `unsigned`, to get the full `0x00`→`0xFF` range. Personally I'd convert to `unsigned char` (instead of `unsigned int`), for which the value of `0xDD` is `221`.

In the code below I've also made a safety adjustment to your loop condition.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lpBuffers->len-8; i = i + 8)
//                                         ^^
{
    printf(
        "%02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X"
          "\t\t%c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n",

        static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+1]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+2]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+3]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+4]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+5]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+6]),
        static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+7]),
        (drawable(lpBuffers->buf[i]))   ? static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i])   : '.',
        (drawable(lpBuffers->buf[i+1])) ? static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+1]) : '.',
        (drawable(lpBuffers->buf[i+2])) ? static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+2]) : '.',
        (drawable(lpBuffers->buf[i+3])) ? static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+3]) : '.',
        (drawable(lpBuffers->buf[i+4])) ? static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+4]) : '.',
        (drawable(lpBuffers->buf[i+5])) ? static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+5]) : '.',
        (drawable(lpBuffers->buf[i+6])) ? static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+6]) : '.',
        (drawable(lpBuffers->buf[i+7])) ? static_cast<unsigned char>(lpBuffers->buf[i+7]) : '.'
    );
}
```

Comment: even when not casting them to unsigned int, the problem is the same and i dont know why there are negative values in my data stream .. usually there shouldnt be any

Comment: @user3125183: Read again. You should cast to `unsigned char`. A negative value for a signed datatype becomes a high, positive value for an unsigned datatype... and, crucially, _vice versa_.

Comment: hmm well at least your "version" of my printf looks better :D ill give it a try

Comment: works like a charm, thanks .... well yeah sure unsigned int .. 4 bytes ... should have figured it <__< i would upvote you but i dont have 15 reputation ^^

Comment: @LemoniscooL: You will soon! :)

Comment: Oh, go on, I'll upboat you for Christmas.

Comment: @MartinJames: Aww you're too sweet!